# call python method of class from c++ code

Tags: c++, python

I can call a python function from c++ code, but I don't like that I must have a wrapper for each type of return value and i don't know how to call method of python class.

here how I call function
    http://codepaste.ru/10354/

question:

1. how to call method of python class?
2. is there any way to implement function that can return different types?

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: question: 1.how to call method of python class? 2. is there any way to implement function that can return different types?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the **first question**, best take a look at the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/c-api/object.html#PyObject_CallMethod). It describes a function

```
PyObject* PyObject_CallMethod(PyObject *o, char *method, char *format, ...)
```

which does, I believe, what you need.

Regarding the **second question:** All Python functions return a `PyObject *`. But that object can be a tuple or a user-defined class, so there can be complex information wrapped in it.